# Extract the last row of an array in Powershell

Tags: powershell, api

I'm using Powershell to extract data via an API. For some reason, the output is providing multiple rows of data, however I'm only interested in the last row.

How do I trim or filter the array so that it only shows me the row e.g. `{"preview":false...`

After I have the last row, I'm going to shift it into a hashtable using ConvertFrom-Json

Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
$output
{"preview":true,"offset":0,"lastrow":true,"result":{"TotalSuccess":"1152091","TotalUnsuccessful":"13759","Total":"1165850","Unsuccessful%":"6.80"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":0,"lastrow":true,"result":{"TotalSuccess":"1204330","TotalUnsuccessful":"14265","Total":"1218595","Unsuccessful%":"6.76"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":0,"lastrow":true,"result":{"TotalSuccess":"1233151","TotalUnsuccessful":"14500","Total":"1247651","Unsuccessful%":"6.75"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":0,"lastrow":true,"result":{"TotalSuccess":"1249102","TotalUnsuccessful":"14714","Total":"1263816","Unsuccessful%":"6.76"}}
{"preview":true,"offset":0,"lastrow":true,"result":{"TotalSuccess":"1262812","TotalUnsuccessful":"14794","Total":"1277606","Unsuccessful%":"6.73"}}
{"preview":false,"offset":0,"lastrow":true,"result":{"TotalSuccess":"1271004","TotalUnsuccessful":"14873","Total":"1285877","Unsuccessful%":"6.73"}}
```

Comment: `1,2,3 | Select -Last 1`.

Answer (score 6):

Multiple options, assuming `$output` is an array or a similarly enumerable collection of things:

```
# using `Select-Object`:
$output |Select -Last1

# using array index
$output[$output.Length - 1]

# using negative array index
$output[-1]

# iterate over collection until you reach the end:
$last = $null
foreach($item in $output){
    $last = $item
}
```

If `$output` is a multi-line string, use the `-split` regex operator to split on newlines first:

```
$output -split '\r?\n' |Select -Last 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. These only seem to extract characters, not the rows

Comment: @Cyclemonkey Updated the answer, please see the last example

Comment: This doesn't appear to split it out either.

Comment: @Cyclemonkey then `$output` is not a string containing multiple lines :) How did you obtain/create the variable in the first place?

Comment: ah! I run the following and it pulls the JSON via the API... $output = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url -Credential $cred -Body $body